# Excel - How to conditional format a cell with a time format when its time is one hour before current time?

Tags: excel

I would like to condition format (highlight) a cell that has a time format. Let's call it `A2`.

I understand that current time can't be derived using `=now()-date()`.

How can I set the condition in condition format to have a highlight effect when `A2` is within 1 hour before current time?

For example:

```
current time = 1000
A2 = 0900
```

`A2` will be highlighted

```
current time = 0000
A2 = 0900
```

`A2` will not be hightlighted

```
current time = 0930
A2 = 0900
```

`A2` will be highlighted

```
Current time = 0900
A2 = 0900
```

`A2` will not be highlighted

Comment: Does this need to work across midnight, e.g. Highlight 23:30 when time is 00:15?

Answer (score 0):

for range A1:A7 you can do
    `= A1 < HOUR(NOW()) - 1`

A1 - the first cell in the range

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Click `cell B2` and go to `Home > Styles > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula ...`, enter this formula in the formula bar:

```
=((A1-B1)*1440>0)*((A1-B1)*1440<=60)
```

What `(A1-B1)*1440` does is to convert the time difference to minutes so I can easily do greater than 0 but less or equal to 60 mins.  You can also apply the settings to more cells (I used `=$B$1:$B$4` in my example) in the `Conditional Formatting Rule Manager`.  Please try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this formula in conditional formatting

`=MOD(NOW()-A2,1)*24<1`

That will also work across midnight if required

Note: time change won't trigger a re-calculation, so if you want this to be dynamic you'll need to force that somehow